# Importing a JavaScript file into JSP page: why this is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

This code is executed when I run it inside a `.jsp` page enclosed by `<script>` tags. Nevertheless, when I use it in a `.js` file imported to the same `.jsp`, the script doesn't work, being ignored by browser as it would not exist.

```
$('#dgProjects').datagrid({
            onSelect: function(index, row){
                alert(index + ' - ' + row)
            }   
        });
```

In spite of this behavior, I can run other scripts in this `.js` file, like

```
function alerting(message){
    alert('A new message was received: ' + message);
}
```

Any idea on what I'm forgetting/doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: on time: #dgProjects is a datagrid build by JEasyUI

Comment: `doesn't work` says nothing about errors, what does happen etc. Not much of a problem description

Comment: @charlietfl, edited. Thank you.

Comment: Did you look in browser console to see if it loads..is code wrapped in `document.ready`? Any errors.

Comment: No, there's no errors being showed in browser's developer console. Actually .js file is being loaded in browser. The statement above is put as plain as it is, directly in the .js document. This strategy worked for me some months ago, now I'm returning to this project and doing some changes, when it stopped to work for now.

Comment: Looks like you're running the code too early to me. like it's running before an element with `id='dgProjects'` exists.

Comment: @KevinB, if you have an interest, please check my answer. Finally I've found a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

After some tries, I achieved a solution, in spite of not knowing perfectly what are the reasons for the fact that I was able to run scripts in .js file called from .jsp page and not to reference $('#Element') in the same way:

```
<script>
        $.getScript('${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/site/home.js', function() {});
</script>
```

After that, code ran unincidentally.

Comment: uhm. if that works, this would likely work too: `$(document).ready(function () {$('#dgProjects').datagrid({
            onSelect: function(index, row){
                alert(index + ' - ' + row)
            }   
        });});` which is what i was hinting at in my comment.